# Does passive need direct object or indirect object of a verb

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

Here My Question is about direct object or indirect object of a verb when using passive form not abut "happened".

Can't we use the passive form if we don't have direct or indirect object.

> This was happened to me.
>
> This was happened 7 years back.
>
> I was kissed by her.(correct)

Adding:

I'm trying to tell one incident:

> This has happened to me when I was about 18 years old.

or

> This happened to me when I was about 18 years old.

Comment: The first two sentences seem ungrammatical to me. The verb *happen* doesn't take a direct object and therefore cannot be in the passive voice.

Comment: *"This happened to me when I was about 18 years old."* is the grammatically correct form.  Note: Your sentence does not work well with the word ***'this'*** referring to something you say after the sentence.  **Good:** *"I won the lottery. This happened a year ago."* **Bad:** *"This happened a year ago. I won the lottery."*  If this confuses you, you could ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Prefacing with a more generic category doesn't change the nature of the question. I could ask "What is 1+1?" and someone might say, "Duplicate of HOW TO ADD". Then I edit as: "This is not about addition, it's about the nature of arithmetic operators. What is 1+1?" It's still the same question.